# Toad unicode input problem

Tags: unicode, toad

In toad, I can see unicode characters that are coming from oracle db. But when I click one of the fields in the data grid into the edit mode, the unicode characters are converted to meaningless symbols, but this is not the big issue.

While editing this field, the unicode characters are displayed correctly as I type. But as soon as I press enter and exit edit mode, they are converted to the nearest (most similar) non-unicode character. So I cannot type unicode characters on data grids. Copy & pasting one of the unicode characters also does not work.

How can I solve this?

Edit: I am using toad 9.0.0.160.

Comment: Your best bet to get Toad questions answered quickly (and accurately) is to post them on the Toad mailing lists here: http://www.toadsoft.com/maillist.htm I work for Quest, and I can vouch that the developers, product managers and support teams patrol those email lists pretty regularly. I subscribe, but I just read for the most part, since it's hard to beat the actual developers when it comes to answers. They don't usually read StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

We never found a solution for the same problems with toad.  In the end most people used Enterprise Manager to get around the issues.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 2):

Quest officially states, that they currently do not fully support Unicode, but they promise a full Unicode version of Toad in 2009: http://www.quest.com/public-sector/UTF8-for-Toad-for-Oracle.aspx

An excerpt from know issues with Toad 9.6:

> Toad's data layer does not support UTF8 / Unicode data. Most non-ASCII characters will display as question marks in the data grid and should not produce any conversion errors except in Toad Reports. Toad Reports will produce errors and will not run on UTF8 / Unicode databases. It is therefore not advisable to edit non-ASCII Unicode data in Toad's data grids. Also, some users are still receiving "ORA-01026: multiple buffers of size > 4000 in the bind list" messages, which also seem to be related to Unicode data.

Comment: I think that's not the case because I am the only one with this problem in the company.